# Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition - Where is MFC?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to create a new `MFC` project using `Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition`.

When I chose File --> New --> Project, I did NOT find `MFC`!

How can I add this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2005 Express <s>doesn't include</s> purposely excludes MFC or ATL. For that, you gotta' pay. Same with VS2008 Express.

Answer (score 1):

Express Edition limited something there. I cant find MFC on Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. Try to get the Professional version.